# Per instance settings on blocks with context?

Tags: blocks, 7

Blocks normally have a single global configuration.

What options are there to provide "per instance" settings on blocks, so that I can vary them depending on where they are displayed, when they are handled with [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Context module for block positioning - you don't need to make any changes at /admin/structure/block page.

All configuration are done in context /admin/structure/context

If you need to display the same block on different places/pages/regions - just create different context for each condition.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. How does this allow me to change configurations? Can I somehow set block config within Context, and I'm just missing that?

Comment: While creating context - you can specify different conditions (such as user roles, urls) and also select region where block will be displayed.

Comment: But that's not what I'm asking about. I'm wondering about the settings _on_ the block, as handled by [hook_block_configure](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_configure/7).

Comment: Aha, i see. i don't see such settings in context.

Answer (score 0):

it's not good answer but it's fair work around for now !

implement

> Implements hook_preprocess_block

help to overwrite some values

also i use value from request like $_GET['q']

i hope to see another answer